# move canvas on key down

Tags: wpf

I want to move canvas right when I press ->.
I set event KeyDown and this is method for event

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key==Key.Right)
    {

    }
}
```

But what to write inside `if`?`Canvas.setLeft` doesn't work

```
 <Canvas x:Name="totle" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
        <Ellipse  Name="yio" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40" Height="30" Width="30" Fill="Beige"/>
        <Line X1="40" Canvas.Left="67" Canvas.Top="51" StrokeThickness="40" Stroke="Red" Height="10" Width="45" Fill="#FFD86464" OpacityMask="Red" />
        <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="70" Width="70" Height="20" Fill="Beige"/>
    </Canvas>
```

Comment: It depends ... please show the XAML with your Canvas.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. For positioning the parent of the control (the parent of your Canvas) is crucial.

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this effect, first use a `RenderTransform` and name it canvasTranform:

```
<Canvas x:Name="totle" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="canvasTransform" />
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Ellipse  Name="yio" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40" Height="30" Width="30" Fill="Beige"/>
    <Line X1="40" Canvas.Left="67" Canvas.Top="51" StrokeThickness="40" Stroke="Red" Height="10" Width="45" Fill="#FFD86464" OpacityMask="Red" />
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="70" Width="70" Height="20" Fill="Beige"/>
</Canvas>
```

Then, in your event handler, reference the `TranslateTransform` by name and set the `X` property:

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            canvasTransform.X = 100;
        }
    }
```

If you the transform to be additive (the canvas keeps moving right as you press the right arrow), add to the `X` property each time:

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Right)
        {
            canvasTransform.X += 100;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The RenderTransform will work but in LayoutTransform the TranslateTransform has no effect.

Comment: @LPL - You're right, thanks. My guess is he doesn't want the transform to affect the layout anyways, so I just removed the one with LayoutTransform.

Comment: @OP - If you do actually want the transform to affect the layout, just comment and I'll try to think of a way to do it for you.